# C# Sending information to and opening external URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, https, response

I have a web application (lets call it Application A) where a user have to log in. Some information is then retrieved from a web service at login, and after successful login, the home page is displayed.

Recently we have developed a "portal" application (Application B) which also requires the user to log in, after which certain other information is retrieved. Different other smaller applications are then hosted within this "portal" site (Application B) and, depending on the users access, these applications are then made available to the user via the "portal".

We now want users to only log into the "portal" (Application B) and present them with an option to start Application A from the portal, without them having to log into Application A again. The login information from Application B must be used. I need to send certain information from Application B to Application A and then launch it.

What would be the best way to go about doing this? They both run in HTTPS (SSL). I have read about Response headers as an option, but then some say that it cannot be used. Query strings are not an option here.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try using headers? Who says it cannot be used and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to encrypt their credentials and send it with their request to access the other application.  Both applications will have to know the encryption key used, which could be hard coded.  The other application, if not already authenticated, decrypts the credentials and calls the web service.

Or

If all applications can access the same database, when the user wants to go to the next app, generate a key and store it in the database.  Send that key with the user in the url to the next app.  That app checks that key is in the database and if exists and not older than say 5 minutes, it sets the user as authenticated.  *This way will keep you from having to manage encryption keys and storing raw passwords.*